# Предпоказ из формы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть форма. В ней несколько полей и загрузка картинки. 
Требуется вывод преподказа из формы после нажатия кнопки Добавить. 
т.е
Нажал кнопку добавить, внизу формы вышло то, что сделали. Опять нажал добавить, рядом еще появилось и так много раз. + возможность удалить(отменить добавление).

После нажатия кнопки  Продолжить, данные отправятся PHP, там уже знаю как сделать.

После выходит опять форма и все, что было добавлено - вывелось. и для них требуется возможность удалить(отменить добавление).

Есть ли что-то подобное уже в готовом виде?)

Comment: для этого надо всего написать код, после того как код написан, приделать его к вашему коду, как приделается, запустить, раз запустилось, то работает, а в php вы и сами знаете.

Comment: > внизу формы вышло то, что сделали

что сделали ? добавили ? добавили что ?

Comment: смешно, весьма

Comment: @GBread чего сказать то хотели ? **Вопрос непонятен**

Comment: Не совсем понятно что именно должно выйти внизу формы, но если вам нужно что бы внизу формы добовлялось еще одно поле, то тут надо в `js` добавить html контент. К примеру самое простое

    $('button').on('click',
        function() {
           $('form').append('<input type="text" >')
        }
    )